# How do I grab multiple commits from a different release branch?

Tags: version-control

I am currently a maintain a module on Drupal.org. I had high hopes of working on a 8.x release, however I ran out of time and made extra commits in the 7.x-2.x branch.  Now my git repository looks like something below:

```
  7.x-2.x     x - x - x - x - x - x - x 
                       \
  8.x-1.x               x
```

How do bring 8.x-1.x up to speed with the 7.x-2.x.  What commands do I need to run.  I thought I would ask the question here as Drupal.org is a little bit unique in how it organizes its repositories.

Comment: I know I can try a simple merge, but last time I did that I lost a branch, which (I think) I do not want to do with a Drupal.org release repository.

Answer (score 2):

A normal merge should work fine. It shouldn't remove the merged branch. If it does, you can always recreate the branch.

If you want to take just some of the commits, use "git cherry-pick".